# Перенос строк в TextFormField() (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development, flutter, dart

Как я могу сделать ввод в TextFormField() так, чтобы при достижении определенной длины, строка обрезалась и курсор переносился на новую строку

Так выглядит код поля для однострочного ввода

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        hintText: 'What do people call you?',
        labelText: 'Name *',
     ),
    onSaved: (String value) {
        // This optional block of code can be used to run
        // code when the user saves the form.
    },
    validator: (String value) {
       return value.contains('@') ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
    },
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При указании минимального `minLines` или максимального `maxLines` количества строк автоматически включается режим переноса избыточного текста на новую строку:

```dart
      TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          hintText: 'What do people call you?',
          labelText: 'Name *',
        ),
        minLines: 3,
        maxLines: 5,
        onSaved: (String value) {
          // This optional block of code can be used to run
          // code when the user saves the form.
        },
        validator: (String value) {
          return value.contains('@') ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
        },
      )
```